# How to load/show asp.net form(panel) on click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a form with some data inside my .aspx webform

I also have a button. When i click that button, i need to load another, exactly the same form, but without refreshing the site, so i wouldn't loose any data in the previous form.

How can i do this?

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="labelOpis" runat="server" Text="Opis izdelka"></asp:Label><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="inputTextArea" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <span style="color:red"><asp:Label ID="errorOpis" runat="server"></asp:Label></span><br />
    <asp:Label ID="labelKolicina" runat="server" Text="Količina"></asp:Label><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="inputKolicina" type="number" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

```
<button id="btnAddNewProduct" class="form-control">Add new product</button>
```

**UPDATE**

**.aspx**

```
<script src="Content/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Content/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Content/hideForm.js"></script>
<script src="Content/live-preview.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
        } );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.ticket').click(function () {
            $(".skrijPrvo").slideToggle();
        });
    });
</script>

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder><br />         
                    </div>
                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" class="form-control" Text="Zaključi nakup"/><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" class="form-control" Text="Nazaj"/><br />
                <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Dodaj nov artikel" class="ticket" OnClick="AddControl_Click" /><br />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**ascx**

```
<body>
<div id="accordion">
    <h3>Dodaj nov izdelek</h3>
    <div class="skrijPrvo">
       <asp:Label ID="labelOpis" runat="server" Text="Opis izdelka"></asp:Label><br />
       <asp:TextBox ID="inputTextArea" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
       <span style="color:red"><asp:Label ID="errorOpis" runat="server"></asp:Label></span><br />
       <asp:Label ID="labelKolicina" runat="server" Text="Količina"></asp:Label><br />
       <asp:TextBox ID="inputKolicina" type="number" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
       <span style="color:red"><asp:Label ID="errorKolicina" runat="server"></asp:Label></span><br />
       <asp:DropDownList ID="inputDropdownList" class="form-control" runat="server">
           <asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="Material1" Value="Material1"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="Material2" Value="Material2"></asp:ListItem>
           <asp:ListItem Text="Material3" Value="Material3"></asp:ListItem>
       </asp:DropDownList><br />
       <span style="color:red"><asp:Label ID="errorDropDown" runat="server"></asp:Label></span><br />
       <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" class="form-control" onchange="readURL(this)" /><br />
       <span style="color:red"><asp:Label ID="errorFileUpload" runat="server"></asp:Label></span><br />
       <asp:Image ID="fileUploadImg" class="form-control" runat="server" Height="300px"/><br />    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: load another form and next? do you want to append it below existing form? or hide existing and show new form...?? or anything else

Comment: hide existing (not loose any data) and append new one below existing @Reddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for dynamically added [User Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53.aspx).

Add a new User Control to your project and put your form in it.

```
<asp:Label ID="labelOpis" runat="server" Text="Opis izdelka"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="inputTextArea" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<span style="color: red"><asp:Label ID="errorOpis" runat="server"></asp:Label></span>
<br />
<asp:Label ID="labelKolicina" runat="server" Text="Količina"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="inputKolicina" type="number" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

On the page that will contain the Controls you need to add a PlaceHolder

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="AddControl" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="AddControl_Click" />
```

Then you need to (re)create the User Controls on every Page Load and the Add Control button click.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check if the viewstate exists and if so, build the controls
    if (ViewState["controlCount"] != null)
    {
        addControls(Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["controlCount"]));
    }
    else
    {
        //if not add just 1 control
        addControls(1);
    }
}

private void addControls(int n)
{
    //loop the amount of controls and add them to the placeholder
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        UserControl1 control = (UserControl1)LoadControl("~/UserControl1.ascx");
        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(control);
    }

    //save the control count into a viewstate
    ViewState["controlCount"] = PlaceHolder1.Controls.Count;
}

protected void AddControl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //add an extra control
    addControls(1);
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can access the values of the TextBoxes by setting a property in the User Control with a getter and a setter.

```
public string textBox1
{
    get
    {
        return TextBox1.Text;
    }
    set
    {
        TextBox1.Text = value;
    }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

And now you can access them from the Parent by looping all the controls and get the value.

```
foreach (UserControl1 control in PlaceHolder1.Controls)
{
    Label1.Text += control.textBox1 + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: thanks, this will work. just need to customize it a little bit!

Comment: this definitely works, but when i try to hide my first form, it kinda starts to fade away, than he page seems to reload and the form shows again. but im not sure page really reloads, because data stays in. but then i have 2 forms instead of one

Comment: That's the whole idea right? To `load another, exactly the same form`? If not you can just add 2 forms statically and show/hide them with jQuery or code behind.

Comment: yes indeed it is. but the first one doesn't hide on javascript, because i dont think javascript works on <asp:button> buttons, only on <input type=button"> . correct me if im wrong. I would add 2 forms, but that kinda wouldn't be enough because as long as user clicks "add new" it should open up new form. this works with your solution

Comment: seems ive fixed it

Comment: Just remember, you can access asp buttons too. Just use `$("#<%= Button1.ClientID %>").offset().top`. And `<input type=button">` (what an asp button also is in HTML) will also do a form post when clicked (PostBack).

Comment: alright thanks! last question. i was suppose to enter all this data in my database, coded in .aspx.cs file. now that everything is in my usercontrol.ascx file, i'm missing all the textbox values. how do i access them?

Answer (score 0):

add you code inside

```
<asp:updatepanel>
```

tag and add onclick properties to you button. After that you can write your business code in code behind (aspx.cs). This is default ajax in asp.net